# What are these objects near the Cosmonaut's faces?

Tags: spacesuits, soviet-union, equipment, astronauts

The obituary "[Aleksei Leonov, First Man to Walk in Space, Dies at 85](https://nyti.ms/2Vx9TYm)", includes this photo:

[image]

What are the white objects alongside each of the cosmonaut's mouths? Are they microphones? If so, why two?  Whatever they are they seem quite large and possibly uncomfortable. Also quite prominent compared to what I thought spacesuits normally look like.

Comment: Head crabs inside the helmets, clearly.

Comment: Headsets (шлемофоны)

Comment: They use two microphones left and right to the mouth for redundancy, if one mic fails, the other one will work hopefully. Same story for the two earphones.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These are two microphones of the cosmonaut's headset (шлемофон - hat with headphones and microphones). Two microphones reserve each other.
[image]
The ДЭМШ-microphone possessed considerable resistance to noise interference and selectivity to voice. For many decades, the ДЭМШ-microphone was installed in almost all Soviet military and professional civilian radio stations and communication systems.
[image]

Alexey Leonov:
[image]

Comment: They were still big in 2011 https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/shuttle/sts-135/hires/jsc2011e040299.jpg

Comment: I do not think that this microphone can be reduced in size. In conventional microphones, the membrane is located on one side of the microphone body. The DEMSh microphone had openings providing access to the membrane on both sides of the housing. External noise came more or less evenly from both sides of the  housing and acted on the membrane from two directions, mutually suppressing. The voice sounded from only one side of the microphone, influenced the membrane from only one side, and was perfectly transmitted by the microphone to the amplifier circuits of the radio station.

Comment: Cool description of the elegant noise cancellation mechanism, thanks.

Comment: By "reserve each other" did you mean that they were redundant, perhaps in case of a malfunction?

Comment: Google translates "ДЭМШ" to "WHH" which means nothing to me... what is it really?

Comment: This is a regular electrodynamic microphone - no electronics inside. In fact, you need to know the scheme of the suit's radio station. I do not think it is online. 
Дифференциальный Электромагнитный Малогабаритный Шумостойкий - Differential Electromagnetic Small-sized Noise-Proof. MiG-23 - only one ДЭМШ-microphone: https://static.aviaforum.ru/attachment-files/2019/02/1372952_cd00d6eaa9a5164ed792acf99a0a785b.jpg

Comment: @DaveInCaz ДЭМШ is DEMSh - sounds like an acronym. My guess is D for differential (дифференциальный), E for electromagnetic (электромагнитный), M for small-sized (малогабаритный), and Sh for noise-resistant (шумостойкий). Ironically, what's small-sized for 60's seems huge today.

Comment: Why did they have two of them, though? A backup in case one failed?

Comment: @nick012000 Perhaps the concept is similar to the headset for the tank crews - Two laryngophones are connected in series with each other. Perhaps this somehow suppresses the strong noise more and enhances the voice. An important property during the flight of a rocket - very noisy flight stage.

Comment: @Agent_L I think reliability is more important then size.

Comment: On Ebay translated as: MICROPHONE ELECTROMAGNETIC DIFFERENTIAL NOISE-RESISTANT DEMSH-1A RUSSIA